# How to remove last 2 positions in split and get remaining first value.?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Let's say string is a variable file name like few examples below:

1. file1_name_cr_001.csv
2. file2_name1_name2.nn.123.456_updt_000.csv
3. filename_2012.444.1234_utc_del_004.csv

The length of last 8 string values will always remain fixed i.e. (_001.csv,_000.csv,_004.csv). We need to only extract values = **cr, updt, del**

How can we get the value as single value before _cr,_updt,_del.?
any suggetions.?

output should get like this:
file1_name/cr/001
file2_name1_name2.nn.123.456/updt/000
filename_2012.444.1234_utc/del/004

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got the below results.

First, I took a sample file name in set variable.

[image]

Then, I got the string from start to **length-8**.

```
@substring(variables('sample'),0,sub(length(variables('sample')),8))
```

[image]

**For end folder:**

```
@replace(split(substring(variables('sample'),sub(length(variables('sample')),8), 8),'.')[0],'_','')
```

[image]

**For Start folder:**

```
@substring(variables('before_8'), 0, lastIndexOf(variables('before_8'), '_'))
```

[image]

**For middle folder:**

```
@split(variables('before_8'), '_')[sub(length(split(variables('before_8'), '_')), 1)]
```

[image]

**Result folder structure:**

```
@concat(variables('start'),'/',variables('middle'),'/',variables('end'))
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Give this variable in copy activity source folder path and it will generate the folder structure for you.**

For multiple file names, first store all file names in an array then use a ForEach and inside ForEach do the same operations as above.

Comment: Based on your answer, I build it in single line and I got the output. Thanks for your Help        @concat('test987','/',substring('W_R_T_Y_DE_20221926.csv',0, lastIndexOf(substring('W_R_T_Y_DE_20221926.csv',0,sub(length('W_R_T_Y_DE_20221926.csv'),13)),'_')),'/',split('W_R_T_Y_DE_20221926','_')[sub(length(split('W_R_T_Y_DE_20221926.csv','_')),2)],'/',first(split(last(split('W_R_T_Y_DE_20221926.csv','_')),'.')))